Handling unsuccessful documents upsert / delete via CosmosDB v3 Bulk API
I've migrated my application using Azure CosmosDB SDK to v3 (version 3.43.1) and I'm using the bulk functionality to upload somewhere between 200 and 1000 items.
Using the BulkExecutor and its configuration I was getting 100% success rate when uploading-- all documents were saved.
In V3 I'm getting 429 response, and only some documents are saved. I'm not sure how I should handle those that were not saved.
ClientOptions setup:
var options = new CosmosDbOptions
{
  AllowBulkExecution = true,
  MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
  MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = 19,
}

I'm using the BulkOperations wrapper as described in the docs.
My main method for bulk uploading looks like this:
public async Task<BulkOperationResponse<TDocument>> ImportAsync(IEnumerable<TDocument> documents)
{
     var bulkOperations = new BulkOperations<TDocument>(documents.Count());

    foreach (var document in documents)
    {
        bulkOperations.Tasks.Add(CaptureOperationResponse(_container.Value.CreateItemAsync(document, new PartitionKey(document.PartitionKey)), document));
    }

    var response = await bulkOperations.ExecuteAsync();
    return response;
}

After inspecting the BulkOperationResponse<T> I often see that only a chunk of documents, were saved.

I have the same issue when trying to bulk delete documents via a method:
public async Task<BulkOperationResponse<TDocument>> DeleteAsync(IEnumerable<TDocument> documents)
{
    var bulkOperations = new BulkOperations<TDocument>(documents.Count());

    foreach (var document in documents)
    {
        bulkOperations.Tasks.Add(CaptureOperationResponse(_container.Value.DeleteItemAsync<TDocument>(document.Id, new PartitionKey(document.PartitionKey)), document));
    }

    var response = await bulkOperations.ExecuteAsync();

    return response;
}

I'm using a shared throughput for 4 containers - 400 RU/s.
How do I need to retry uploading of the failed documents? Does it need to be handled by the SDK, or should I retry in my code?

FYI 400 RU/sec is really low, even for a single container (even worse if any of your containers have > 1 physical partition). Perhaps configure for auto-scale to avoid the throttling?

V3 is faster than the older V2 Bulk Executor, so it's sending more data within the same second than with V2, that's why you are getting the 429s. Either reduce the data (send less at a time) or increase the RU.

Thanks David and Matias for your comments. It brought my attention to the fact, that it could be not only a code issue, but an infrastracture issue as well. I answer my question to give more context and what solution I ended up with.

Thanks for your comments and answers. I analyzed how the code behaves in previous version vs. V3
I noticed that upserting 100 documents in BulkExecutor took over 2 seconds and consumed over 2 000 RU.

In V3 it took 7 seconds, consumed almost 2 000 RU, while some of the documents failed.

So I decided to upscale before my code to a significantly larger throughput and downscale after the operation finishes. This gave me the desired results.

I did some reading up and there are more ways to handle it, such as:

switch from manual throughput to auto-scale
switch to serverless throughput

But due to my setup, I decided to stick with manually increasing the throughput for the time of my operation.

You should let it be handled by the SDK. It has already implemented a retry handler that has been thoroughly tested, and that's aware of the difference between transient and other errors.
If all you care about is uploading all documents you can just increase the MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests and MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests. In your case it'll probably be enough to only increase the attempts as you're still well within your wait time limit.
One of the initial documents you upload might repeatedly return a small x-ms-retry-after-ms (retry delay instruction). New uploads will create a race condition where new uploads might be initiated before the previous ones have successfully retried. As a result only a few documents fail the retry mechanism you observe.
Edit:

You should use the built-in retry mechanism when one is available, unless you have specific and well-understood requirements that make a different retry behavior more appropriate.

Microsoft docs
